# Using and or in conditionals for readability instead of && ||

Tags: php, operators

Often when I am writing PHP I construct conditionals like this:

```
if(1 === $var1
   and 2 === $var2
   or 1 == $var3) {
   // do something here maybe
}
```

I think it makes them easier and more natural to read. *I know this is probably laughable when I am using Yodas though.*

The reason I have each condition on its own line prefaced by `and` or `or` is because it makes it easier to comment part of the statement out when debugging.

Is there any disadvantage to doing this compared with the "usual" `||` and `&&`?

Comment: the separate line thing is kind of nice. But what does that have to do with `and` vs `&&`, or  `or` vs `||`? The `&&` operator has higher precedence than `and`, so using them is not equivalent.

Comment: @dnagirl You are right, absolutely nothing to do with the question just felt like explaining it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no significant functional difference in PHP between `and` and `&&`, nor betweeen `or` and `||`.

The only difference between them is that they are considered as different operators, and have different positions in the order of operator precedence. This can have a big impact on the results of complex operations if you neglect to wrap things in brackets.

For this reason, it is generally a good idea to use one or other style of operators, and stick with it, rather than mixing between the two in the same code base (this is also a good idea for readability). But the choice if which pair of operators to use is fairly immaterial.

Other than that, they are basically the same thing.

See here for the PHP operator precedence: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

(note the different positions in the table of the `and` and `or` vs `&&` and `||`)

Comment: I'd argue that differing operator precedence is a significant functional difference.  Especially because one is higher precedence than assignment, while the other is lower.  That means that `$a = $b and $c` has a completely different meaning than `$a = $b && $c`

Comment: @Frank: I agree it's significant, and I agree it is important to know the difference. I wouldn't call it *functionally* different though, because the stand-alone functionality of the two operators is identical. But I guess it's just a linguistic argument; we're basically agreed, and I've given your answer +1.

Answer (score 6):

`or` and `and` **do not have the same operator precedence** as `||` and `&&`.  This means that in for certain values of expressions`[a]` and `[b]`, `[a] and [b] != [a] && [b]`.  This may create non-obvious bugs.

[image: PHP operator precedence]

Note that one is higher precedence than assignment, while the other is not.  This is a subtle difference, and even if you understand it, other developers reading your code may not.  As a result, I personally recommend using *only* `&&` and `||`

Ruby's operators are similar to PHP's in this regard.  [Jay Fields published a simple example of the difference](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/08/ruby-operator-precedence-of-and-which.html).

Comment: Maybe not only but rather together? Use in pairs, be coherent to avoid subtle, hard to catch bugs, if you feel the need to use `and` use `or` with it.

Comment: Agreed: best to pick one pair and stick with it.  Mixing the two, or, god forbid, replacing one with the other for aesthetic reasons is where you get in trouble.

Comment: Interesting to note that there isn't a symbolic operator for `xor`, so you have to use the named operator in that case. I don't use `xor` much, but if you do then it may affect your choice of which style to use for the sake of consistency.